# VS Code showing not on localhost

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

**Whenever I tried to run my code using VS Code on PowerShell this show**

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

**and** **also it's not loading page overview on localhost or giving error of**

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you installed the PowerShell extension for VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I did can you check that once? @MathiasR.Jessen